# Do enzyme-substrate reactions show reversibility(to a considerable amount)?

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry

I was studying about the catalysts of enzyme-substrate reactions. My biology book says that if the density of product gets high the enzyme-substrate reactions get slower. It quite sounded like [Le Chatelier's Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Chatelier's_principle). But Le Chatelier's principle only works for reactions in which backward reaction happens to a considerable amount. But I am not sure if it is the normal case for enzyme-substrate reactions.

So, Does enzyme-substrate reactions show reversibility(to a considerable amount), or my reasoning is somewhere wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many enzyme catalyzed reactions that are reversible. In such cases, buildup of product may slow and eventually stop the net reaction as you reach equilibrium conditions. Product binding to the active site or to a secondary allosteric binding site may also inhibit the catalytic reaction. This can occur even in the case of irreversible enzymatic reactions.